# Undeclared variable error when using mtype with Jspin

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin

I am new to `Jspin` and `Promela`. I tried to implement the following system:

> A home alarm system can be activated and deactivated using a personal ID key or password, after  activation the system enters a waiting period of about 30 seconds, time that allows users to evacuate the  secured area after which the alarm is armed, also when an intrusion is detected the alarm has a built in waiting period or delay of 15 seconds to allow the intruder to enter the password or swipe the card key thus identifying himself, in case that the identification is not made within the allocated 15 seconds the alarm  will go off and will be on until an id card or password is used to deactivate it.

This is the code:

```
mtype = {sigact, sigdeact};
chan signal = [0] of {mtype};
/*chan syntax for declaring and initializing message passing channels*/



int count;
bool alarm_off = true; /*The initial state of the alarm is off*/

active proctype alarm()

{
off:
    if 
    :: count >= 30 -> atomic {signal!sigdeact; count = 0;alarm_off = false; goto on;}
    :: else -> atomic {count++; alarm_off = true; goto off;}
    fi;

on:
    if
    :: count >=15 -> atomic { signal!sigact; count = 0;
    alarm_off = false; goto off;}
    :: else -> atomic {signal!sigact; alarm_off = true; goto off;}
    fi;

pending:

     if
     :: count >= 30 -> atomic {count = 0; alarm_off = false; goto on;}
     :: count < 30 -> atomic {count++; alarm_off = false; goto pending;}
     fi;
}
```

When I run the code with `Jspin` I get this message:

```
Error: undeclared variable: sigact
```

But I declared this in the header.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/mtype.html) of `Promela`, you are using `mtype` correctly.

In fact, I cannot reproduce your error with `spin` version `6.4.3`, so I suspect this is a specific issue of `Jspin` not being correctly updated.

Unless you want to use `spin` instead of `Jspin`, you can try the following work-around, *which should work even with `Jspin`*:

```cpp
#define sigact   0
#define sigdeact 1
chan signal = [0] of {short};   // or bool for only 2 values

...
```

---

Since no one ever reads from `signal`, I assume the system model is *incomplete* and that more processes will be added later on.

1. Be aware that, in the following *instruction sequence*:

   ```
   atomic { signal!sigdeact; count = 0; alarm_off = false; goto on; }
   ```

   the **atomicity** will be [*temporarily lost*](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/atomic.html) by `alarm` because `signal` is a *synchronous channel* (it has size `0`) and so another process *has to* be immediately scheduled for reading the message being sent.
2. In `off` state, when `count >= 30` you reset `count` back to `0`, set `alarm_off = false` and then go to state `on`. In `on` state, you immediately set `alarm_off` back to `true`. Is this intended? It looks like some mistake, perhaps you meant to go to state `pending`.
3. By reading the description of your system, it looks like the `alarm` is missing some kind of `input` signal. I suspect you are using the `signal` channel differently from its intended purpose.
4. Shouldn't the model have some transition from state `pending` to `off`, in case the proper *personal ID*/*password* is used?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have two questions acccording to you answer: `How` can I pass the input to the given `proctype` function, called `alarm` ? (according to the OP question). Furthermore, suppose we have wrote the `proctype` function which pass the `key` or `passoword` to `alarm` device. How can we adapt the `alarm` function based on given `password` or `key`.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai you should open your own question, including the necessary pseudo-code, as comments on stackoverflow may be deleted at any point in time for no reason and it's difficult to discuss certain issues in the limited space of a comment.

Comment: At this answer I can start a bounty bonus for you if you can help me. That's the reason i wrote the comment here. Do you want to post the question to another answer ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I will gladly help you, but in a new separate question which clearly illustrates your problem. Be sure to tag it with `promela` and `spin`, and I'll catch it. :-)

Comment: I post a question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272662/how-can-i-bind-the-given-input-to-another-proctype